# MySQL Query double query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data in tbl_ordetails and then update data in tbl_cart, but when I try to insert data, the result is always "failed"
, i don't know what's the problem. please help me

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{




$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$customer=$_POST['customer'];

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetails (fullname, address, phone_number, city, customer) VALUES ('$fullname, $address, $phone_number, $city, $customer')";
$query1 = "UPDATE tbl_cart SET status ='Ordered' WHERE customer=['$customer']";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

   if(($conn->query($query1) === TRUE) && ($result->num_rows > 0)){
            echo "success";
            exit;

    }
    else{
         echo "failed";
         exit;

    }


}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem is here `customer=['$customer']`, Query should be `"UPDATE tbl_cart SET status ='Ordered' WHERE customer='$customer'";`

Comment: this is not the best way to do it but your result only calls $query not $query1

Comment: @Noman i try that too, but the result is the same

Comment: @Didi what is the best way sir ?

Comment: $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1); run both query

Comment: just like Norman said you can so that or mysqli_multi_query() http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Your code is suceptable to SQL injection. Be sure to use prepared queries. Not only will it help avoid SQL injection, it will also take care of properly escaping and quoting your variables.

Comment: @sloanthrasher (susceptible)

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. Fat-fingered that one. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Your missing loads of quotes in...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetails (fullname, address, phone_number, city, customer) 
      VALUES ('$fullname, $address, $phone_number, $city, $customer')";
```

It's taking all of the values and building 1 value.  Should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetails (fullname, address, phone_number, city, customer) 
      VALUES ('$fullname', '$address', '$phone_number', '$city', '$customer')";
```

Your update should be (minus [])

```
$query1 = "UPDATE tbl_cart SET status ='Ordered' WHERE customer='$customer'";
```

Even better would be to use prepared statements and bind variables though.

**Update:**

```
   $result = $conn->query($query);
   if ( $result === false ) {
       echo "error:".$conn->error;
       exit;
   }

   if($conn->query($query1) === TRUE){
            echo "success";
            exit;

    }
    else{
         echo "failed:".$conn->error;
         exit;

    }
```

Comment: sir, this is the result "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I've added a new part to the code, mainly to show an error if the query fails.  BUT this assumes your connect is something like `$conn=new mysqli(...);`. This uses the object version of the api

Comment: Just removed the `$result->num_rows`, this isn't needed as the check for the insert failing is now done in the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem lies in this line of code 
if(($conn->query($query1) === TRUE) && ($result->num_rows > 0)){

You implement row counts `$result->num_rows > 0` but i did not see where you are using  **sql select query statement** so where are you getting the row counts. is it supposed to be used when inserting data or when you are selecting data from database.

I am not mysqli fan but PDO

you can try something like this

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{




$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$customer=$_POST['customer'];

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetails (fullname, address, phone_number, city, customer) VALUES ('$fullname, $address, $phone_number, $city, $customer')";
$query1 = "UPDATE tbl_cart SET status ='Ordered' WHERE customer=['$customer']";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

   if($result){
            echo "success";
            exit;

    }
    else{
         echo "failed";
         exit;

    }


}
?>
```

I can rewrite the code more easier using PDO

Again your script is not sanitized or validated and you are vulnerable to Injection and may be buffer overflow Attack